# How do i add online GeoServer layers on android mobile app

Tags: geoserver, google-maps, android

I am trying to develop an android app, and in this app I want to display a Google map and on this map I also want to add some layers on the Map which I have created from GeoServer.

Basically my requirement is that I want a Google map with some layers of GeoServer in my android app. which layers are online on my server not on my localhost

I am new for the android app as well as GeoServer.